# Crud SpringBoot + Angular: Why is the data not stored but deleted from the database every time I restart the execution of the code?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating an application where some customer information is managed. The code works however known that every time the code is restarted the data from the database is totally lost.
I just put the SpringBoot code.

RestAPIController.java

```js
package crudapp.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import crudapp.model.Customer;
import crudapp.model.Message;
import crudapp.service.CustomerServices;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
public class RestAPIController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerServices customerServices;
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> addNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        try {
            Customer returnedCustomer = customerServices.saveCustomer(customer);
            
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Upload Successfully!", 
                                            Arrays.asList(returnedCustomer), ""), HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Fail to post a new Customer!", 
                                            null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);           
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/retrieveinfos")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> retrieveCustomerInfo() {
        
        try {
            List<Customer> customerInfos = customerServices.getCustomerInfos();
            
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Get Customers' Infos!", 
                                                customerInfos, ""), HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Fail!",
                                                null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/findone/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> getCustomerById(@PathVariable long id) {
        try {
            Optional<Customer> optCustomer = customerServices.getCustomerById(id);
            
            if(optCustomer.isPresent()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Successfully! Retrieve a customer by id = " + id,
                                                            Arrays.asList(optCustomer.get()), ""), HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failure -> NOT Found a customer by id = " + id,
                        null, ""), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failure",
                    null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/updatebyid/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> updateCustomerById(@RequestBody Customer _customer, 
                                                                    @PathVariable long id) {
        try {
            if(customerServices.checkExistedCustomer(id)) {
                Customer customer = customerServices.getCustomerById(id).get();
                
                //set new values for customer
                customer.setFirstname(_customer.getFirstname());
                customer.setLastname(_customer.getLastname());
                customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
                customer.setAge(_customer.getAge());
    
                // save the change to database
                customerServices.updateCustomer(customer);
                
                return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Successfully! Updated a Customer "
                                                                        + "with id = " + id,
                                                                    Arrays.asList(customer), ""), HttpStatus.OK);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failer! Can NOT Found a Customer "
                        + "with id = " + id,
                    null, ""), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failure",
                    null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);           
        }
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deletebyid/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> deleteCustomerById(@PathVariable long id) {
        try {
            // checking the existed of a Customer with id
            if(customerServices.checkExistedCustomer(id)) {
                customerServices.deleteCustomerById(id);
                
                return new ResponseEntity<Message> (new Message("Successfully! Delete a Customer with id = " + id, 
                                                        null, ""), HttpStatus.OK);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failer! Can NOT Found a Customer "
                                                        + "with id = " + id, null, ""), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Failure",
                    null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Customer.java

```js
package crudapp.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    
    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @Column
    private String address;
    
    @Column
    private int age;
    
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
    
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }
    
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    
    protected Customer() {}
    
    public Customer(String firstname, String lastname, String address, int age) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id=%d, firstname='%s', lastname'%s', address=%s, age=%d", 
                                id, firstname, lastname, address, age); 
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```js
package crudapp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import crudapp.model.Customer;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{
}
```

CustomerServices.java

```js
package crudapp.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import crudapp.model.Customer;
import crudapp.repository.CustomerRepository;

@Service
public class CustomerServices {
    
    @Autowired CustomerRepository repository;
    
    public Customer saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return repository.save(customer);
    }
    
    public List<Customer> getCustomerInfos(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    
    public Optional<Customer> getCustomerById(long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
    
    public boolean checkExistedCustomer(long id) {
        if(repository.existsById((long) id)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return repository.save(customer);       
    }
    
    public void deleteCustomerById(long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```js
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: The property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` will mean schema is dropped before it is created if you don't want that to happen use `update` value or initialise the schema using sql script independently and then use `validate/none` value for the property. Also remove `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: So you just put the word update instead of create?